# How does the formaldehyde leak into the food from bamboo cutting board?

Tags: gravity, everyday-life

http://food.thefuntimesguide.com/2010/07/bamboo_cutting_board.php

> Some bamboo cutting boards are glued together with adhesives that have formaldehyde in them — ***which could eventually leak into and contaminate food.***

I wanted to understand the logic behind the above claim in italics.

The glue is **between** the sheets of bamboo cutting board. So, if I use only one side of cutting board all the time, will the gravitational force not stop the glue from going upwards and mix in the food?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Gravity is *very very weak* that your applied stress can easily overcome it. The shear force you apply through your knife doesn't *just* cut the onion or meat or whatever food, but it's also transferred to the board. If you ask someone to hold the board, while you cut those onions - he can easily experience this force.

Moreover, bamboo sticks have pores on them through which the formaldehyde adhesive can leak out (what that link suggests *can be* true, because I haven't observed it)...

Comment: Ah, so many people should be dying because of these boards! Thanks for the answer. BTW, can that glue be "seen" on the board after it travels upwards?

Comment: @user462608: I don't know whether *people die* due to that reason (It maybe harmful depending on the amount used) . BTW, I don't think the leaking adhesive can be seen. Even if it's colored, the negligible amount of volume that drips out of it can't be seen by our naked eyes. Moreover, I have a thought that they use negligible amount of HCHO like 0.1 ppm or so which is not so harmful ;-)

Comment: `Moreover, I have a thought that they use negligible amount of HCHO like 0.1 ppm or so which is not so harmful` Are there any sources which support this statement?

Comment: @user462608: Hmmm... [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urea-formaldehyde) says that concentration levels exceeding 3-5 ppm maybe harmful. I guess those guys use less than 0.1 ppm or so. Quite unlucky that I didn't get any references ;-)

Comment: Thanks, but I think it is better to throw away the board since we won't know what level of HCHO have they used until we get cancer due to it! The board isn't worth the risk.

Comment: @user462608: It's totally your wish. I won't argue that. You're welcome BTW ;-)

Comment: @user462608 Just consider carefully *where* and *how* you throw it away, so you don't put somebody else at risk from exactly the same thing. (Whether or not it is a real risk I leave for others to decide.)